# Generate a pyramid using PHP For Loop and HTML

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I made a script where it creates a pyramid using a php for loop and html table elements, but the pyramid isn't how I want it yet.
The code:

```
<?php
echo "<table width=400px";
echo "<tr>";
//Inner Loop
for ($x = 0; $x <= 8; $x++) {
//Outer loop
    for ($z = 1; $z <= $x; $z++) {
        echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=black></td>";
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Right now it looks like this:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: that is just a simple css issue. remove the borders, remove the margins

Comment: try adding CELLSPACING=0 to the table itself and it looks like your missing a closing > on your table at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add cellspacing=0 to table

```
<?php
echo "<table cellspacing=0 width=400px";
echo "<tr>";
//Inner Loop
for ($x = 0; $x <= 8; $x++) {
//Outer loop
    for ($z = 1; $z <= $x; $z++) {
        echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=black></td>";
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: That did the job! So stupid I didn't think of that. Thank you so much! :)